# firebase deploy gives blank screen in react project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have hosted my react project on firebase, I have used same command and instruction, which is mention in this URL, https://www.robinwieruch.de/firebase-deploy-react-js/ but when i run the URL, it is giving me blank screen, even my firebase.json file is same as mentioned

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

still i am getting blank screen, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Did you first use "npm run build" to make it ready to deploy?

Comment: yes i did it, but not working

Comment: A comment said changing a dependency's version in pakage.json from `react-router-dom@5.0.0` to `react-router-dom@4.3.1` made it work as it was the version the author used at that time. Try it and give me a feedback please.

Comment: i did that already but it is not working

Comment: Make sure you run commands on correct sequence: firebase login->firebase init->npm run build->firebase deploy. Also try adding `"redirects": []` to your `firebase.json`. And mostly the case is that the `public` directory's name might not be `build` but something else - check that too.

Comment: i got the issue, it is issue of react now it is working,  thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please explain how exactly did you get it work so that others could learn from you? Thank you. In your question as edit: or better answer your own question by posting an answer.